# xgboost4j - spark evaluate requires RDD[(Double, Double)]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, prediction, xgboost

I try to use xgboost4j with spark 2.0.1 and the Dataset API. So far I obtained predictions in the following format by using `model.transform(testData)`

```
predictions.printSchema
root
 |-- label: double (nullable = true)
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- probabilities: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- prediction: double (nullable = true)


+-----+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
|label|            features|       probabilities|prediction|
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
|  0.0|[0.0,1.0,0.0,476....|[0.96766251325607...|       0.0|
|  0.0|[0.0,1.0,0.0,642....|[0.99599152803421...|       0.0|
```

But now I would like to generate evaluation metrics. How can I map the predictions to the right format? [XGBoost-4j by DMLC on Spark-1.6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36770190/xgboost-4j-by-dmlc-on-spark-1-6-1) propose a similar problem, but I could not get it to work for me.

```
val metrics = new BinaryClassificationMetrics(predictions.select("prediction", "label").rdd)
would require RDD[(Double, Double)]
```

instead of `predictions.select("prediction", "label")` which looks like

```
root
 |-- label: double (nullable = true)
 |-- prediction: double (nullable = true)
```

Tryping to map it to the required tuple like:

```
predictions.select("prediction", "label").map{case Row(_) => (_,_)}
```

fails to work as well.

## edit

reading a bit more in sparks documentation I found http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.evaluation.BinaryClassificationEvaluator which supports ml instead of ml-lib e.g. Datasets. So far I could not successfully integrate xgboost4j in a pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good example https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/jvm-packages/xgboost4j-example/src/main/scala/ml/dmlc/xgboost4j/scala/example/spark/SparkModelTuningTool.scala how to use xgboost4j in a spark pipeline. In fact, they have an XGBoostEstimator which plays well in a pipeline.